# Difference between Partial VIews and User Controls in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, partial-views

Can anyone please tell what's the exact differences between partial views and user controls in an MVC app?
Which one is feasible to use? I am using user controls for filling my views which have one or more tabs(which i have added using Ajax control toolkit).
I want to know about advantages/disadvantages while using partial views and user controls.

Thanks,
Kaps

Answer (score 16):

I mostly agree with Ryan. However one point to consider though is that user controls have an implementation of events whereas partial views do not.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: What you said is one of the most important difference between them. Thanks for reminding that also.

Comment: in asp.net mvc is there any concept about event. if we work with user control then can we implement like event driven programming?

Answer (score 9):

Partial Views and User Controls are basically the same thing.  User Controls are just a way of  distinguishing between regular Views and Partials.  When you see the "Partial.ascx", it's immediately obvious that it's a Partial because the icon is different in Visual Studio.

There's nothing stopping you from using a regular *.aspx file as a Partial.  In fact, some people do exactly this, and prefix their aspx Partial names with an underscore (ex: _UserStatus.aspx).

My personal preference is to use the ascx files instead because it's easier to tell that something is a partial at a glance.